# json preserve original data order

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, text, templating-engine

I am rendering following data

```
set firewall family inet filter v4-test term accept_1 from protocol lilla
set firewall family inet filter v4-test term accept_2 then accept
set firewall family inet filter v4-test term accept_3 from source-prefix-list v4-test
set firewall family inet filter v4-test term accept_3 from destination-port 1
set firewall family inet filter v4-test term accept_3 from destination-port 2
set firewall family inet filter v4-test term accept_3 then accept
set firewall family inet filter v4-test term access_4 from source-address x.x.x.x/32
```

via ttp templating

```
parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
parser.parse()
results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
results_dic = json.loads(results)
```

Output of rendering is a json file

```
[
    {
        "v4-test": {
            "accept_2": {
                "action": "accept"
            },
            "accept_1": {
                "protocol": "lilla"
            },
            "accept_3": [
                {
                    "source-prefix-list": "v4-test"
                },
                {
                    "destination-port": "1"
                },
                {
                    "destination-port": "2"
                },
                {
                    "action": "accept"
                }
            ],
            "access_4": {
                "source-prefix-list": "x.x.x.x/32"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Problem: I want the output data to keep the order of original data. Any hint?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you also post your `ttp_template`?

Comment: Here below the ttp template. For brevity i omit some group like destination port

`<group name="{{ filter }}">
<group name="{{ term }}">
<group>
set firewall family inet filter {{ filter }} term {{ term  }} from protocol {{ protocol  }}
</group>
<group>
set firewall family inet filter {{ filter }} term {{ term  }} from source-prefix-list {{ source-prefix-list  }}
</group>
</group>
</group>`